# Cannot return data from a controller in laravel and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Am fairly new to Laravel and Ajax so you'll forgive me if am making a stupid mistake. Am trying to return a response from a controller, it works when i do all the logic in the routes file,  but when i copied the code to my controller it doesnt work.

Heres my route

```
  Route::post('student', 'StudentPDetailsController@store');
```

and the js file, called custom.js

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#saveDetails').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  var dataString = {'studentphonenumber':$('#sphonenumber').val(),
              'studentidnumber':$('#sidpp').val(),
              'studentgender':$('#sgender').val(),
              'studentbirthdate':$('#datepicker').val(),
              '_token':$('#token').val()
              }

   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'student',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert('Your personal details have been updated')
    }


  });


  });

 });
   })(jQuery);
```

Heres the blade template:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default panelshadow">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3   class="headinpanel">Personal    Details</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="studentPersonalDetails" role="form" method="POST" action="#">
                    <input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sphonenumber" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">National ID/Passport</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sidpp" name="idnumber" value="{{ old('idnumber') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Gender</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select name="gender" id="sgender" class="form-control">
                                <option value="male">Male</option>
                                <option value="female">Female</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary saveBtn" id="saveDetails">
                                <h4>Save Details</h4>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and finally StudentPDetailsController

```
   public function store()
    {   
    if(Request::ajax()){
    return Response::json(Request::all());
    }
   }
```

Comment: What result do you get than?

Comment: time to learn about implementing error handling. Also problem description is far too vague...we have no idea what is or isn't working when you show both client side and server side code and simply say .... *"not working"*

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @dennismiano What is the error in console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Response object to the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
...
$request->all()
```